# woo commerece short codes not working on all posts

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a short code to display short description in woo commerce but it is not working on all posts. It is displaying the short description on some posts and not on others.

**Function to create that short code in functions.php**

```
    function product_shortdesc_shortcode( $atts ){
    // use shortcode_atts() to set defaults then extract() to variables
    extract( shortcode_atts( array( 'id' => false ), $atts ) );

    // if an $id was passed, and we could get a Post for it, and it's a product....
    if ( ! empty( $id ) && null != ( $product = get_post( $id ) ) && $product->post_type = 'product' ){
        // apply woocommerce filter to the excerpt
        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $product->post_excerpt );
    }
}
// process [product_shortdesc] using product_shortdesc_shortcode()
add_shortcode( 'product_shortdesc', 'product_shortdesc_shortcode' );
```

**The way i am getting the data in my single.php file**

```
$custom = get_post_custom(get_the_ID());
$my_custom_field = $custom['woo_id'];
foreach ( $my_custom_field as $key => $value ) {
echo do_shortcode('[product_shortdesc id='.$value.']');
}
```

PS: in my normal post i have a custom field which has the value of product id of the product in woo commerece.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are expecting shortcodes to function which no longer exist. On new installs, these pages won't be created, but if you are updating you may already have those pages in place.

Although the upgrade script does attempt to trash them for you, this might not have happened if they were customised. Delete them. Delete edit-account and change password, then go to your 'my account' page and click the change password/edit account links. You'll be taken to and endpoint which offers the same functionality.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.remicorson.com/woocommerce-2-1-x-endpoints-vs-shortcodes/#comment-11527

Answer (score 0):

Short Code must not echo code instead return the things that needs to be rendered

Change this

```
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $product->post_excerpt );
```

to

```
return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $product->post_excerpt );
```